# Powershell Run Stored Procedures in Parallel in Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, powershell

We want to run all stored procedures in parallel. The powershell script finds a list of stored procedures in the database (only have 5 right now), and runs them simultaneously. This code seems to be working. Is there anymore efficient or recommended method to conduct this, or does the code seem valid?

```
Workflow TestRunParallelExecute
{
    $ServerName = "localhost"
    $DatabaseName = "testrun"
    $Procedure_Query = "select name from sys.procedures"
    $Procedure_List = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Query $Procedure_Query)

    ForEach -Parallel ($Procedure in $Procedure_List.Name)
    {
         Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Query $Procedure 
    }
}
TestRunParallelExecute
cls
```

I read many resources below, wanted to come up with easy way using Powershell new ForEach -Parallel function.

[Run stored procedures in parallel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173265/run-stored-procedures-in-parallel)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193805/executing-stored-procedures-in-parallel

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803101/run-several-stored-procedure-in-parallel-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question:

> Is there anymore efficient or recommended method to conduct this, or
>   does the code seem valid?

I'm not aware of a more *efficient or recommended* method, but I *believe* I did validate the basic code you are using.

I created 5 identical stored procedures (SP1 - SP5) that each have a `WAITFOR '00:01:00'` to force the procedure to wait for 1 minute before exiting.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[sp1];
go
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    waitfor delay '00:01:00'
END
```

I tweaked your original Powershell code to only select stored procedures where the name was `like SP%` to make sure that only SP1 - SP5 would be selected.

I started your Powershell script and immediately went back into SSMS to execute [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) so I could see whether the stored procedures were being executed in parallel and noted that all 5 stored procedures were executing.

[image]